# Can continuous random variables ever have positive probability on a single point?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

From a textbook:

> Continuous random variables can lead to confusion. First, note that if $X$ is continuous then $\mathbb{P}(X = x) = 0$ for every $x$.

But then later:

> Let $F$ be the CDF for a random variable $X$. Then:
>
> $$
> \mathbb{P}(X = x) = F(x) - F(x^-)
> $$

**Question:** Can't it very well be the case that $F(x) - F(x^-) \ne 0?$? For example, $f$ could suddenly jump positively by $1$ at $x$, causing $F$ to jump by $1$ at $x$.
 Hence wouldn't it follow that $\mathbb{P}(X = x)$ need NOT be zero for all $x$?

Comment: If $F(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=x_0$, then $F'(x)$ will not exist at $x=x_0$. So $F'(x)$ doesn't exactly make sense as a _function_ in that context. (That  said, people do talk about such entities; they're known as distributions or 'generalized functions.')

Comment: What function is meant by $f$?

Comment: $f$ is meant to denote the probability density function from which $F$ is derived.

Answer (score 2):

A random variable $X$ is continuous if its CDF $F(x)$ is continuous. Since $F$ is always non-decreasing and right continuous, it follows that $F$ is continuous if and only if $F(x)=F(x-)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

And since $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=F(x)-F(x-)$, this shows that $X$ is continuous if and only if $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Does it also follow that $F$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is continuous? So that you can think "if this random variable is described as (absolutely) continuous, then both $F$ and $f$ are implied to be continuous and exhibit none of the pathological behavior I was alluding to above "?

Comment: $X$ can be continuous without even having a pdf $f$. And pdfs are often discontinuous. Consider for instance the pdf for the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

Comment: But the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ generates a discontinuous DCF $F$ *and* a discontinuous $F' = f$. Am I correct here? So does it still follow that $F$ is continuous iff $f$ is continuous?

Comment: For the uniform distribution, $F(x)=0$ if $x\leq 0$, $F(x)=x$ if $0\leq x\leq 1$, and $F(x)=1$ if $x>1$. So $F$ is continuous.